# Cannot retrieve repository meta data repomd.xml for repository Fedora 14-i386 installation under VirtualBox

Tags: linux, fedora, virtualbox

I am trying to install **Fedora-14-i386-DVD.iso** using **VirtualBox-5.0.10-104061-Win.exe** on windows 7.

But as soon as I check the option **[_] Fedora 14 - i386** as additional repositories, I get an error.

These are the links from where I have downloaded

- Fedora iso : https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/14/Fedora/i386/iso/
- Virtualbox: https://download.virtualbox.org/virtualbox/5.0.10/

This is the error message I got:
[image: Error message]

**How can I install it correctly?** If I go without this option my guest addition doesn't build correctly.

I want to do it all off-line means without internet using rpm, iso or other files.

Answer (score 1):

Fedora 14 is years (4 years!) after EOL (end of life). Current version is 23. The repositories and packages for outdated releases are long gone. Please try to install some up-to-date version.

Comment: working with Fedora10 both (x86-64 and i386), both are working no problem with them. Just asking if someone using It. Same problem I got with Fedora16 also, I know it is also outdated.

Comment: Can you help me to get complete iso for Fedora-23, Here on this website (https://getfedora.org/en/workstation/download/). I am getting only live version (1.4GB) , Where I want to install it, internet is not connected there. **I have to do it(installation) offline**.  So I need complete .iso.

Comment: If you want to do offline installation, you can't check the online repositories.

Comment: At:Jakuje Sorry I didn't get you. Where I am doing a wrong step. Where I am checking online repositories in my process. Please help me.

Comment: checking **[_] Fedora 14 - i386** as additional repositories adds repository, it adds online repository and if it is not able to connect it prints error. If you want to do offline install, the first repository "Installation Repo" should be enough.

Comment: @AnuragChauhan Live ISOs don't need internet connection to install. The "live" thing means you can boot with the DVD into a fully working desktop. Once there, look for an option to install into hard drive.

Comment: Hi, All I tried it again just to check my luck with same iso file copied it at a different place (another drive Or partition)  then It was working.  So I am sharing here just to inform you that you can try same copy paste, and It may work for you. I thought It was a read problem of this .iso file.